# Вывод оповещения на сайте в определённое время с интервалом

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите как можно реализовать вывод оповещения на сайте с 12 до 16 в будние дни через 30 секунд после захода пользователя? Сейчас вывод оповещения производиться по нажатию кнопки.

```
<script>
const toastTrigger = document.getElementById('c-dinner')
    const toastCDinner = document.getElementById('cDinner')
    if (toastTrigger) {
    toastTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastCDinner)
    
        toast.show()
    })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ну так проверяйте по дате, смотрите дни недели и число, совпадают или нет, а потом если проверки пройдут удачно, используя setTimeout выводите оповещение.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Нельзя ли подробнее. А еще лучше с примерами. Спасибо.

Comment: А можно ваши попытки решения? Если вам нужны работники вам сюда - https://www.weblancer.net/

Comment: @ΝNL993 я бы с удовольствием с вами поделился своими «попытками», но увы — полный профан. :(
Спасибо за помощь в указании пути.

Comment: Тогда учите JavaScript, я не вижу никакого другого пути в вашем случае, за вас полностью работу делать не будут, только есть вы не заплатите соответственно. В интернете полно документации, тот же [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript), https://learn.javascript.ru/, или [видео-уроки в YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=javascript+курсы), самое главное всё бесплатно, нужно лишь желание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const run = () => {
    const date = new Date();
  const hour = date.getHours()
    const day = date.getDay()
  
  if (
    (hour >= 12 && hour < 16) &&
    (day >= 1 && day <= 5)
  ) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('message')
    }, 1000 * 30)
  }
};



run()
```

UPD:

```
const run = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const hour = date.getHours()
    const day = date.getDay()
    
    const toastCDinner = document.getElementById('cDinner');

  if (
    (hour >= 12 && hour < 16) &&
    (day >= 1 && day <= 5)
  ) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        toast.show()
    }, 1000 * 30)
  }
};



run()
```

Comment: а как мне теперь к этому привязать свое оповещение?